# AngularJS and ExpressJS routing conflicts

Tags: angularjs, express

I am trying to pass an index value, for an array, into a route, so I can use the id to load a specific object into a detail view.

Controller that injects the index and changes path

```
location.path('/detail/'+index);
```

$routeProvider that handles the detail routing

```
.when('/detail/:index', { 
    controller: DetailViewCtrl, templateUrl: 'partials/detail' 
});
```

Express script that handles the partial loading

```
app.get('/partials/:partial', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('partials/' + req.params['partial']);
};
```

If I pass in an index of 5 then I expect the URL to look like "localhost:3000/detail/5", and I do get that in my browser but the server returns a 404 error where is was trying to look for some weird URL "localhost:3000/detail/partials/detail." I have no clue where the "detail " that is added before the partial is coming from.

It would be nice to know what is happening behind the scenes and how to fix the problem. How can I pass custom variables in the route and not have express freak out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend the `templateUrl` with `/`:

```js
.when('/detail/:index', { 
   controller: DetailViewCtrl, 
   templateUrl: '/partials/detail' 
});
```

or insert the `base` tag under the HTML `head` element as in:

```html
<base href="/" />
```