# Express routing conflicting with AngularJS routing.

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, url-routing

I have routing code of the following nature in Express :

```
app.get("/profile/:param", function (req, res)
```

This is coinciding with the path routing provided by AngularJS. For instance, when an Angular view of the nature `/profile/someparam#view1` is loaded,the new URL pattern is picked up by Express, which assumes it to be of the type `/profile/<someparam>`. This is causing the controller associated with view1 to be called infinitely thereby crashing the page.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution from here: [AngularJS and ExpressJS routing conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493605/angularjs-and-expressjs-routing-conflicts). Basically, in the angular routing file, the `templateURL` needs to be pre-pended with a '/'. For e.g, in my angular routing code, I had to change

```
$routeProvider.when('/routeName', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html', 
        controller:'rcontroller' 
});
```

to

```
$routeProvider.when('/routeName', {
        templateUrl: '/view1.html', 
        controller:'rcontroller' 
});
```

Comment: It's common practice to put your templates into a folder called "partials", which have little chance of conflicting with any backend APIs. Take a peek at the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/tree/master/app/partials) project

Comment: @MichaelTang, yes I do put my views in a partials directory, in general. But even if my views were in a partial directory, my problem would not be solved.